# Grails "stuck" in always logging all sql queries

Tags: hibernate, grails, logging, tomcat7

I once wanted to log sql queries in Grails so I added in datasource

`logSql = true`

and in log4j

`trace 'org.hibernate.type'
debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'`

The problem is later when i removed them again, grails is still logging all the sql queries.

My application is deployed on 4 different platforms, and no matter how many times I rebuild and deploy , on 1 of the platforms it's still always logging every sql query (even though it's the same war).

can there be a change to do in tomcat? or anything else to try ?

Comment: Do you have some externalized config on the 'bad' server?

Comment: nope, just the datasouce and the `logSql = false` is in it. was just thinking about something can another war affect it ?

Comment: Possibly, is this app or another deployed to ROOT or webapps?

Comment: are you sure the deploy process is fully stopping tomcat removing all files / as in the extract app folder and re-installing - it maybe that you need to ensure it is fully stopped flushed out started again. tomcat has some temp folders you could try clearing them out - don't think it's that though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to actually remove `logSql = false` all together, for some reason, even if it's false it will always log, i think the config only searches for "logSql" and not the value